# Change color when hovering over li

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm programming a simple wordpress page and want to change the background color of the menu bar (on the top right) when hovering over it. It's on this website: https://www.happylogo.be/.
I normally just do this with 'add additional css' which just is a css file.
The weird thing is that I beleive my selector code is right because when I add 'visibility:hidden;' It rapidly disappears and reappears again when hovering over the li items.

The css code I use now:

```
#menu-primary-coach li:hover{
   /*#menu-primary-coach is the id of the lu*/
   background-color: #c7143a !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. 
How can I change the background color when hovering over the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the `<a>`tag inside of your `<li>` is actually overriding the hover state with black.

```
#primary-nav ul li:hover > a, #sticky_menu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

You can remove this style or also set the hover state of the `<a>` to your desired color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by this line of CSS. There is a hover on the `<a>` within the `<li>`. Since the page is using xhtml the hover style should be on the `<a>` rather than the `<li>`. If you use HTML5 it can be on the `<li>`.

```
#primary-nav ul li:hover > a, #sticky_menu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```